# Is it possible to conquer the entire map in Heavy Gear's Tour of Duty mode?

Tags: heavy-gear

In the 1997 ActiVision game *Heavy Gear*, there is a Tour of Duty secondary game mode. In the mission selection screen, there is a circular map with a horizontal split in the middle. The split is jagged with multiple vertices, but initially starts flat. As you complete more and more missions, the split seems to encroach on the other side's territory. As you know, the north fight the south in the game's story. I always played on the North side. As I played more and more hours as a kid, it seemed like the split would slowly creep south.

So I wonder, is it possible to "beat" Tour of Duty? Is it possible to conquer, little by little, the entire map? Would anyone have indication of having done so? A screenshot, or even better, a save file?

Answer (score -1):

there is 2 tour of duty cut scenes on the CD it self. You have to have unlimited ammo, and invincibility off. otherwise the game goes on forever till you turn the cheat options off. I played 4000 missions with cheats on and the map never got conquered. I played and suceeded 2000 missions without cheats and the still 75% of the map was not conquered. I never beat it but I saw 2 movies both north death and south death on a file on CD 2. Played for years, never made it past Commident or Colonel

Comment: Can you upload save files?